# How to automatically save the output image file in a specified folder?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filepath, edge-detection, canny-operator

I am using Canny edge detection on images. Since my original 10 images are in the path folder, `C:\Users\X\Desktop\FoodRGB` as `01.jpg`, `02.jpg`, `03.jpg` and so on, I want to save all my output images in the folder `C:\Users\X\Desktop\FoodCanny` as `01.jpg`, `02.jpg`, `03.jpg`.

I figured that I have to use `imwrite()` function to write the output images in a specific folder but I am not sure about the big idea.

The following code I am using is saving the images as `0%d.jpg` in `FoodCanny` Folder I manually created.

```
for k = 1:10        
img = sprintf('C:\Users\X\Desktop\4\Food Canny\0%d.jpg',k); 
imwrite(canny_image, 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\4\Food Canny\0%d.jpg');
end
```

Comment: Your last line should be, `imwrite(canny_image, img);`, since you are constructing the string using `sprintf` in `img` variable.

Comment: Also, you could simplify the like that creates `img` to use `fullfile`, like so: `img = fullfile('C:','Users','AHII','Desktop','4','Food Canny', [num2str(k) '.jpg']);`

Comment: You have to use double "\" in the definition of the file path in the `sprintf` (a single "\" is interpreted as an escape sequence -  such as \n for example). Therefore in the call to `imwrite` you have to use the strng you have buitl in `img` instead of writing again the whole filename. Also you have to split the writing sequence in the `for` loop in order to capture the case in which the "number" in the filename is >= 10 otherwiswe it will have a `0` too (010.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you want to get canny edges of all screenshots in the `C:\Users\Asus\Pictures\Screenshots` and save them to the other folder `D:\.` You can do this by :

```
clc;clear all;
fpath = fullfile('C:\Users\Asus\Pictures\Screenshots','*.png');
img_dir = dir(fpath);
for k=1:length(img_dir)
    input_image=strcat('C:\Users\Asus\Pictures\Screenshots\',img_dir(k).name);
    original = rgb2gray(imread(input_image));
    original= edge(original,'canny');
    imwrite(original,strcat('D:\',sprintf('edge(%d).jpg',k)));
end
```